# openvpn: no access to server lan formed by a switch

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

Is there any way to access to openvpn server lan in the following scenario?

**Server1 (vpn server)**

IP (eth1): 10.0.0.199/24

Vpn IP (tun0): 10.8.0.1/24

**Server2**

IP (eth1): 10.0.0.198/24

**Client**

IP (eth1): 192.168.64.2/24

Vpn IP (tun0): 10.8.0.1/24

Only Server1 is publicly open to internet, and servers are connected through a local switch with 10.0.0.0/24 ip range. All machines have ubuntu 16.04 installed, ip-forwarding enabled and ufw disabled.

Client is connected to vpn server, but **can't access** to Server2 by pinging **10.0.0.198**. However, Server2 **can access** to client machine by pinging **10.8.0.4**.

Routes are configured as below:

#### openvpn server.conf

```
route 192.168.64.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.64.0 255.255.255.0"
```

#### ccd/client

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.4/24 10.8.0.1
iroute 192.168.64.0 255.255.255.0
```

EDIT:
Server2 has also this route: `10.8.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.199`

Note: I don't have access to routers/gateways of neither client nor server1. So, I am trying to find a way to access server2 without touching routers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a route on Server2. Try adding this:

```
 ip route add 10.0.8.0/24 via 10.0.0.199
```

Comment: This route is also added, i forgot to mention. Because of this, Server2 can access to client i think. But the opposite is not working.

Comment: Then you need to enable the IP forwarding on your Server1 so it can forward the IP packets between interfaces.

Comment: already enabled on all machines